# ASP.NET Core MVC many-to-many CRUD Operations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, many-to-many, crud, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC with TagHelpers.

My project has entities called "GroupEntity" , "CustomerEntity" and "GroupsCustomerEntity".

I want to add customers to groups from "CustomerController"s "Edit" action. In the  "Form" view of customer there should be a checkbox for every group.

I tried everything i found online but could not do it. So i am just posting my Controller and asking you to tell me what should i do. Here is the github link: [github](https://github.com/exchangel/FCA)

```
public class CustomerEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? Interest { get; set; }
    public string? FindHow { get; set; }
    public string? Note { get; set; }

    //relational prop
    public List<PersonalSessionEntity> PersonalSessions { get; set; }
    public List<GroupsCustomersEntity> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class GroupEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; } //User is the coach of this group.
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    //relational prop
    public UserEntity User { get; set; }
    public List<GroupsCustomersEntity> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class GroupsCustomersEntity : BaseEntity
 {
     public int GroupId { get; set; }
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }
     //relational prop
     public GroupEntity Group { get; set; }
     public CustomerEntity Customer { get; set; }
 }
```

I am pretty sure that my tables correct. Here are my update and save actions in CustomerController.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    
    var updateCustomerDto = _customerService.GetCustomer(id);


    var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel()
    {
        FirstName = updateCustomerDto.FirstName,

        LastName = updateCustomerDto.LastName,
        Phone = updateCustomerDto.Phone,

        Email = updateCustomerDto.Email,

        City = updateCustomerDto.City,

        FindHow = updateCustomerDto.FindHow,

        Interest = updateCustomerDto.Interest,

        Note = updateCustomerDto.Note,

      

    };
    
    return View("Form", viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save(CustomerFormViewModel formData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (formData.Id == 0)
        {
            var addCustomerDto = new AddCustomerDto()
            {
                FirstName = formData.FirstName,
                LastName = formData.LastName,
                Phone = formData.Phone,
                Note = formData.Note,
                City = formData.City,
                Interest = formData.Interest,
                Email = formData.Email,
                FindHow = formData.FindHow,
                
            };

            var result = _customerService.AddCustomer(addCustomerDto);

            if (result)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "This customer already exists.";
                return View("form", formData);
            }
        }
        else //update
        {
            var updateCustomerDto = new UpdateCustomerDto()
            {
                Id = formData.Id,
                FirstName = formData.FirstName,
                LastName = formData.LastName,
                Phone = formData.Phone,
                Interest = formData.Interest,
                City = formData.City,
                Note = formData.Note,
                Email = formData.Email,
                FindHow = formData.FindHow,

            };
          _customerService.UpdateCustomer(updateCustomerDto);

            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
    }

    return View("form", formData);
}
```

And lastly, here is my view. I am using aspTagHelpers, but i have not seen anyone using it.

```
@model CustomerFormViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 offset-2">
        <div class="card" style="border:solid 2px">

            <div class="card-header fw-bold fs-5">
                Müşteri Formu
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">

                <form method="post" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Save">

                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.ErrorMessage))
                    {
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
                        </div>
                    }

                    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
                    

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="LastName" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label asp-for="Phone"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Phone" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="Phone"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label asp-for="City"></label>
                        <input asp-for="City" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="City"></span></div>

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label asp-for="Groups"></label>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Groups.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <input asp-for="Groups" />
                        }
                    </div>

                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <label asp-for="FindHow"></label>
                            <input asp-for="FindHow" type="text" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="FindHow"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <label asp-for="Interest"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Interest" type="text" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="Interest"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <label asp-for="Note"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Note" type="text" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="Note"></span>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-3 float-end">Send</button>

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g25ap6i8VH0) tutorial. But I don't understand his view pages or his linq queries.

And [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4jwpwBd4t4) tutorial has a controller for its join table, which just feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes taghepler can't fit your requirement, You need to write name property manually ,I create a simple demo to show how to use checkbox to update the related model in many to many relationship. Hope it can help you solve this issue.

**Model**

```
public class Group
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> customers { get; set; }
    }

public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<Group> groups { get; set; } = new List<Group>();
    }

public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
        public List<Group> groups { get; set; }
    }
```

**Backend**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var customer = _dbcontext.customers.Include(x => x.groups).Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            var groups = _dbcontext.groups.ToList();
            CustomerViewModel customerView = new CustomerViewModel();
            customerView.customer = customer;
            customerView.groups = groups;

            return View(customerView);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(CustomerViewModel model, int[] groupIds)
        {
            var customer = _dbcontext.customers
            .Include(c => c.groups) // Load associated groups
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.customer.Id);

            if (customer != null)
            {
                // Update customer properties
                customer.Name = model.customer.Name;
                customer.Age = model.customer.Age;

                // Clear existing group associations
                customer.groups.Clear();

                if (groupIds != null)
                {
                    foreach (var groupId in groupIds)
                    {
                        var group = _dbcontext.groups.Find(groupId);
                        if (group != null)
                        {
                            customer.groups.Add(group);
                        }
                    }
                }

                _dbcontext.Update(customer);
                _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("edit");
        }
```

**Frontend**

```
@model CustomerViewModel
@{
    int index = 0;
}

<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="customer.Id" />
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label asp-for="customer.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="customer.Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="customer.Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label asp-for="customer.Age"></label>
        <input asp-for="customer.Age" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger fw-bold mt-1" asp-validation-for="customer.Age"></span>
    </div>
    @foreach (var group in Model.groups)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="groupIds" value="@group.Id"
        @(Model.customer.groups.Contains(group) ? "checked" : "")>
        <label>@group.Name</label>
    }

    <button>Edit</button>
</form>
```

**gif Demo**

[image]